# use a lambda to start a thread which is a class attribute

Tags: multithreading, c++11, lambda

I would like to assign a name to a thread, the thread itself must do this. The thread is a class member of the class foo.
I would like to start this thread with a lambda but unfortunately I get the error message:
*no match for call to '(std::thread) (foo::start()::<lambda()>)*

Can someone explain to me where the problem is?
Previously I had created a temporary thread object, and put this with move on the thread "manage", however, I can then give no name.

```
class foo {

    public:

        int start()
        {
            this->manage([this](){
            auto nto_errno = pthread_setname_np(manage.native_handle(),"manage");           // Give thread an human readable name (non portable!)
              while(1){
                  printf("do work");
              }
            });
            return 1;
        }

    private:
        int retVal;

        std::thread manage;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the lambda in a wrong way, after initialization the manage thread can't be initialized again. you should create a new std::thread and assign it.
the following compiles and indeed prints "manage".

```
class foo {

    public:

        int start()
        {
            manage = std::thread([this]{
              auto nto_errno = pthread_setname_np(manage.native_handle(),"manage");
              char name[16];
              pthread_getname_np(pthread_self(), &name[0], sizeof(name));   
              cout << name << endl;
            });
            manage.join();
            return 1;
        }

    private:
        int retVal;

        std::thread manage;

};
```